# Console output to file

Tags: java, loops, console, output

Basically I'm reading in a file which has 9 shop units and then theirs a bunch of code which does a bunch of calculations from this, anyways I'm having a problem were i'm only getting some of the outputs. This is my code:

```
    }
    if(total > reccomended_max){
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
        System.setOut(out);
        System.out.println("The total staff wages for " + Unitnum + " is £" +total + ", therefore it is higher than the RM");
    }else{
        System.out.println("The total staff wages for " + Unitnum + " is £" +total + ", therefore it is lower than the RM");
    }
```

The "reccomended_max" is a user input number, and then basically if the "total" wage of the shop unit is greater than the "recommended_max" I need it to:

Print the shop unit data to the output file

Else > if its less than.. orint to the console..
When i try random numbers input for the reccomended_max im getting:

```
Please enter the recommended maximum(RM) staff cost: 
900
The total staff wages for Unit One is £824.0, therefore it is lower than the RM
The total staff wages for Unit Two is £0.0, therefore it is lower than the RM
The total staff wages for Unit Three is £504.0, therefore it is lower than the RM
```

To console ^^. and to output file:
The total staff wages for Unit Nine is £935.0, therefore it is higher than the RM

It seems whatever the input is, i'm only getting unit nine displayed in the output file? Anyone know why this could be or is my code too brief to know why??

Comment: You should initialize the output stream outside of the if statement. The else part doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));`
Outside of the if statement. Think maybe that's the problem, but I'm still a beginner so don't hold me to it!